# Error getting while import excel using php

Tags: php, excel, import

I want to import excel using php. I have

```
 public function importexcel()
    {

        $this->img = 'poc.xlsx';
$exceldata = array();
 require 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
try
{
    $inputfiletype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( $this->img);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputfiletype);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $this->img);
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo( $this->img,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

**POC.xlsx**

[image]

But when I load the page I got an error like

> Error loading file "poc.xlsx": Could not open poc.xlsx for reading!
>   File does not exist.

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your path to file is not correct. Please check your file path.

Comment: 'controllers/poc.xlsx'

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should always use absolute paths for files. If the file is in the same directory as the controller, the line with the path should look as follows:

```
$this->img = __DIR__ . '/poc.xlsx';
```

`__DIR__` is a magic constant, whose value always equals the absolute path to the directory of the current file.

Notice that you're using a `require` statement like this:

```
require 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
```

Since you obviously don't have a fatal error informing about an inexistent file, it indicates that the current working directory is not `controllers`, but one above it. So, you could also write

```
$this->img = '../poc.xlsx';`
```

and this would probably work too. But again, it'll be easier to avoid all errors with missing files when you use absolute paths.